# Unable to access textbox variable declared in aspx file from aspx.vb file

Tags: vb.net

I have following abc.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codefile="abc.aspx.vb" Inherits="abc" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
         </head>
         <body>
             <asp:textbox id="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
         </body>
</html>
```

here is abc.aspx.vb file:

```
Partial Class abc
    txtSearch.Text = "HELLO"
```

When i try to use this it gives error: txtSearch is not accesible? 
Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong here?
This is not complete code just a snippet. But i think it gives an idea what am i trying to do.

Comment: Regarding your code snippet... Are you setting `txtSearch.Text` inside of a method, or as the snippet implies are you trying to set it at the class level?  If the latter, I don't believe that's allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Partial Class abc
    txtSearch.Text = "HELLO"
```

If you're trying to set that value at the class level, that's not allowed.  The functionality you'd be trying to achieve with that can be accomplished by setting it in the constructor:

```
Partial Class abc

    Shared Sub New()
        txtSearch.Text = "HELLO"
    End Sub
```

Comment: I figured it out. It was because i was missing abc.aspx.designer file. I think you need that file in order for things to work correctly in new version of .net.